# How can I run a Pygame Zero program from the Command Prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt, pgzero

I can run Pygame Zero programs from idle if I add the necessary code. but when I try to run it from the command line no matter what file or folder I try to put my Pygame zero project in, it will not open a window it only says Pygame 1.9.5. Then, the line beneath that says "Hello" from the pygame community and gives me the main page of pygame's url.

The command I am using to try and run is pgzrun which multiple sources say should work.

I am using Windows 10, and have Pygame installed and Pygame Zero installed. I am using python version 3.7.

Comment: Have you tried just executing the script with your python interpreter?  That’s what I’ve always done and it works. But as far as your question goes, could you please add a minimal, reproducible example to your question?  That’ll help us find what exactly the problem is.

Comment: don't you get any error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you try to run `python your_script.py` ? or `C:/full/path/to/python.exe your_script.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ide-mode.html), add the following line at the **top** of your Python script:

```py
import pgzrun
```

and the following line at the **bottom**:

```py
pgzrun.go()
```

Then run it as a normal Python script, i.e. `python your_script.py`